# Getting value from dynamic text area

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint-online

I have a text area field and I want to get value of that text area so I try to get via javascript like:

```
var body = "Descripción";
var _body = $("div[title='" + body + "']");
```

Text area

```
<textarea rows="10" cols="20" id="Descripci_x00f3_n_9b68a148-3221-43c6-abf3-bb32afd3e51b_$TextField" title="Descripción Campo obligatorio" class="ms-long"></textarea>
```

But I just get object not value.

For some reason when I write in text area this input change with the value I want:

```
<input id="ClientFormPostBackValue_742e5004-4272-4f68-b3b9-a3c9e3d9ba9b_Descripci_x00f3_n" name="ClientFormPostBackValue_742e5004-4272-4f68-b3b9-a3c9e3d9ba9b_Descripci_x00f3_n" type="hidden" value="this is the value I want">
```

How can I retrieve value from this input? Regards

Comment: The selector you provided would not match either of those elements.  The title on neither of them matches the `body` variable exactly, which is what your selector is looking for.

Comment: Whats supossed to be my selector? `ClientFormPostBackValue_742e5004-4272-4f68-b3b9-a3c9e3d9ba9b_Descripci_x00f3_n`? @Taplar

Comment: Or use `^=` to denote that the title should start with that string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var body = "Descripción";
//use `^=` to denote that the attribute should start with a string
var _body = $("textarea[title^='" + body + "']");

console.log(_body.val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea rows="10" cols="20" id="Descripci_x00f3_n_9b68a148-3221-43c6-abf3-bb32afd3e51b_$TextField" title="Descripción Campo obligatorio" class="ms-long">
  Stuff
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to get the data after a button click? if so.

```js
function run() {
    var textbox = document.getElementById("Descripci_x00f3_n_9b68a148-3221-43c6-abf3-bb32afd3e51b_$TextField").value;
    document.write(textbox);
}
</script>
```

```html
<textarea rows="10" cols="20" id="Descripci_x00f3_n_9b68a148-3221-43c6-abf3-bb32afd3e51b_$TextField" title="Descripción Campo obligatorio" class="ms-long"></textarea>
<br/>
<button type="button" onclick="run()">get</button>
```